# Using pre-defined roles in Serverless Framework

Tags: aws-lambda, serverless-framework

The user deploying the application with Serverless Framework don't have permissions to use IAM:

```
Serverless: Checking Stack update progress...
CloudFormation - UPDATE_IN_PROGRESS - AWS::CloudFormation::Stack - my-project
CloudFormation - CREATE_IN_PROGRESS - AWS::Logs::LogGroup - ScheduledLogGroup
CloudFormation - CREATE_IN_PROGRESS - AWS::IAM::Role - IamRoleLambdaExecution
CloudFormation - CREATE_IN_PROGRESS - AWS::IAM::Role - IamRoleLambdaExecution
CloudFormation - CREATE_FAILED - AWS::IAM::Role - IamRoleLambdaExecution
CloudFormation - CREATE_IN_PROGRESS - AWS::Logs::LogGroup - ScheduledLogGroup
CloudFormation - CREATE_FAILED - AWS::Logs::LogGroup - ScheduledLogGroup

An error occurred: IamRoleLambdaExecution - API: iam:CreateRole User: arn:aws:sts::xxx:assumed-role/xxx/xxx is not authorized to perform: iam:CreateRole on resource: arn:aws:iam::xxxxxx:role/my-project-sa-east-1-lambdaRole.
```

Can I use pre-defined roles instead of creating new ones during deployment? How?

Answer (score 2):

yes, you can use already existing roles instead. In order to do that, you need to specify it e.g. this way:

```
provider:
  iam:
    role: arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/execution-role
```

Role specified this way will be used by all your functions.

You can read more about it here: https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/iam

Answer (score 1):

Of course, you can. Just set role ARN while declaring your function in the serrveless.yml file

```
  myLambda:
    handler: path/to/handler.lambda_handler
    role: arn:aws:iam::{ACCOUNT_ID}:role/{YOUR_ROLE_NAME}
    events:
      - http:
          path: path
          private: true
          method: post
          cors: true
```